# Minimum PC spec for Java EE development

Tags: jakarta-ee

I am a Java EE programmer, currently my team and I were using Pentium4 HT with 512MB RAM PC in my development. Due to the company's limited budget, I was thinking to get a "powerful" server for compiling/building the whole web App. my current situation was if I start up a localhost server (either tomcat or glassfish), this really going to kill my low end PC. Thus I was thinking to use the low-end PC for pure compilation, and the server will handling the different type of Java EE supported server. And then package the war file and deploy it to the server for whatever purpose the developer want. That is about the whole idea of the development.

May I know is this an idea solution beside to request my finance to approve the budget?

Comment: My condolences; I'd never want to run any of that gigantic bloated Java stuff without a few gigabytes of RAM. Is a [machine like this](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16883108568) really so far out of reach? Heck, if you could leave off Windows and ditch the high-end video card, a reasonable system ought to be $500 or less...

Comment: you could save money by throwing out the internals and getting a new cpu, motherboard, ram and power supply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the processor, Java EE neeeds RAM. The best option to speed up your development would be to upgrade the RAM to 2 GB, that is a typical amount for Java development (more would be better, but with a 32bit Windows...). Please check your mainboard RAM compatibility before buying ;-)